# How to add lightning component to a navigation menu

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, community-builder

I have created a lightning component and implemented forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes in the component tag.

We are using Customer Service Template. What I want is to add the component in the Navigation Menu. However I do not find any option for the same. Will it be possible to add the Component in the Navigation Menu?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One can add the Lightning component to a Communities page and include that page in the navigation bar, but there is no way to directly add the component to the menu.

For info on adding components to Communities pages, see this page:

[Configure Components for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder.htm)

Comment: I followed the documentation. I have created the component and added the design component to the lightning bundle. However, I am still not sure how to add the design component to the Community Navigation menu.I do not have much idea about Communities and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't add it directly to the menu.  You need to add it to a page, and then add the **page** to the navigation menu.